# Join gives wrong answer

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have 2 tables "**Event_Volunteer_Activity**" in which I am storing the Volunteer who has applied and "**Voluntee_Attendance**" which has the respective attendance for the Volunteer

```
Event_Volunteer_Activity
EventId VolunteerId ActivityId
19      2491          40
19      2491          42

Voluntee_Attendance
EventId ActivityId  VolunteeId
19        40          2491
```

now when I run

```
SELECT Event_Volunteer_Activity.VolunteerId,
       Voluntee_Attendance.VolunteeId,
       Event_Volunteer_Activity.ActivityId
FROM Event_Volunteer_Activity
     RIGHT OUTER JOIN Voluntee_Attendance ON Event_Volunteer_Activity.VolunteerId = Voluntee_Attendance.VolunteeId
WHERE (Event_Volunteer_Activity.VolunteerId = 2491);
```

I am getting

```
  VolunteerId   VolunteeId  ActivityId
  2491             2491       40
  2491             2491       42
```

When I am doing a right or left join I am getting the above answer.. Where I should be getting since **Voluntee_Attendance** doesn't have an attendance taken for **ActivityId**=42

```
 VolunteerId    VolunteeId  ActivityId
      2491             2491       40
      2491             null       42
```

Comment: I really urge you to start using whitespace and line breaks when writing code. A single, very long, line of code is not readable to anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include **ACTICITYID** in linking and Change into **LEFT join**

```
SELECT V.VolunteerId, E.ActivityId
  FROM Event_Volunteer_Activity E
  LEFT JOIN Voluntee_Attendance V

  ON E.VolunteerId = V.VolunteerId
  AND E.activityid = V.ActivityId

WHERE E.VolunteerId = 2491;
```

**Output will be**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are describing a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT eva.VolunteerId, va.VolunteeId, eva.ActivityId
FROM Event_Volunteer_Activity eva LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     Voluntee_Attendance va
     ON eva.VolunteerId = va.VolunteeId
WHERE eva.VolunteerId = 2491;
```

Note that table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try with below query where we add two consition in join table and alias of table for simplicity of code:

```
SELECT EVA.VolunteerId,
       VA.VolunteeId,
       EVA.ActivityId
FROM Event_Volunteer_Activity as EVA
     LEFT OUTER JOIN Voluntee_Attendance as VA ON EVA.VolunteerId = VA.VolunteeId and EVA.ActivityId = VA.ActivityId
WHERE (EVA.VolunteerId = 2491);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT E.VolunteerId, V.VolunteeId, E.ActivityId
 FROM Event_Volunteer_Activity E LEFT JOIN 
 Voluntee_Attendance V
 ON E.VolunteerId = V.VolunteeId
 WHERE E.VolunteerId = 2491;
```